# Migrate from jsdom to phantomJS ? (basic DOM creation)

Tags: node.js, d3.js, phantomjs, jsdom

M. Bostock pointed out that nodejs' jsdom have incomplete support for svg, and, critical for me, doesn't support `getBBox()`. Also, he advised to switch to nodejs' PhantomJS. I checked out but the approach is new to me.

My nodejs + jsdom script create a virtual DOM, with which my d3js plays and is as follow :

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.env(                             // creates virtual page
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // create my DOM hook,
  [ 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',    // add my online dependencies ...
  '../js/d3.v3.min.js',                // ... & local ones
  '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'],

  function (err, window) {
           //my normal JS or nodejs code here !
  }
);
```

**How to migrate this nodejs + jsdom into nodejs + PhantomJS  ?**

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add a reference to M. Bostock's recommendation (regarding jsdom vs. phantomjs)?

Comment: yes sure. Just edit up.

Comment: I meant you - I don't have the reference, I thought you do  :)

Comment: There https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/JyldAkWkTvI/n8thanJeGvAJ ! @user1475331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do this from node.js, you should use a PhantomJS bridge like [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) (*phantom* npm module).

When you don't open a page in PhantomJS, you're actually working in an about:blank page, you need to add '--local-to-remote-url-access=yes' commandline option for the underlying PhantomJS process, so that remote resources can be loaded. Maybe `--web-security=false`, `--ssl-protocol=any` and `ignore-ssl-errors=true` may be necessary.

To inject additional scripts into the DOM, you need to use [`injectJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) for local files and [`includeJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) for remote files. Furthermore, you cannot directly access the DOM in PhantomJS, because it has two contexts. The sandboxed page context ([`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)) has no access to variables defined outside, so you will need to pass them explicitly in, if you need them.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var async = require('async');

function run(page, ph) {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        // page context: DOM code here
        return document.title;
    }, function (title) {
        // node code here
        console.log('Page title is ' + title);
        ph.exit();
    });
}

var remoteScripts = [ "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ];
var localScripts = [ "../js/d3.v3.min.js", "../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ];
phantom.create('--local-to-remote-url-access=yes', '--web-security=false', function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        async.series(remoteScripts.map(function(url){
            return function(next){
                page.includeJs(url, function(){
                    next();
                });
            };
        }), function(){
            async.series(localScripts.map(function(url){
                return function(next){
                    page.injectJs(url, function(){
                        next();
                    });
                };
            }), function(){
                run(page, ph);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to load script lists into the DOM. I used the `series()` function.

Comment: You might need to use a newer PhantomJS version like 2.0 if 1.9.x doesn't provide everything you need.

Comment: Thanks. I'am starting to dig into Phantomjs thanks to your kick starting advices.

Comment: Note: I just listed 3 dependencies for this questions while I actually have ~12 dependencies to pill up, it will quickly looks messy. I'am willing to assess the scalability - maintainability - readability of PhantomJS since I will have to keep teammates updated. Any "passing an array of urls" tricks similar to jsdom ? (I checked out your links, no such thing found !)

Comment: As I am digging into Phontomjs I understand better your post and appreciate it as the global review and tutorial it is. Awesome ! :)

Comment: I added a version with async loading.

Comment: A `if` could make that [a bit shorter](http://jsfiddle.net/kxg5etyy/2/). Note: your answer already deserve a validation or 3 "up votes", but I want to let the space open if someone come with another npm bridge package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75939/discussion-between-hugolpz-and-artjom-b).

Comment: Answer validated! Thanks for your great answer :)